# I'm unable to update my data that is longitude and latitude in my Android app

Tags: php, android, mysql, httpurlconnection

Here is my code

**1.Java Code**

```
class makePOST extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Double> {
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Toast.makeText(update.this, "onPreExecute", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                url = new URL("http://student.96.lt/Android/update.php");
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                String postdat = "code" + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(mCode, "UTF-8") + "&" + "latitude" + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(mLatitudeText, "UTF-8") + "&" + "longitude" + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(mLongitudeText, "UTF-8");
                //String postdat=mLatitudeText;
                conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(postdat.getBytes().length);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                OutputStream OS = conn.getOutputStream();
                InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();

                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
                bufferedWriter.write(postdat);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                // Get output
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                    sb.append("\n");
                }

                in.close();
                bufferedWriter.close();
//            java.io.BufferedOutputStream out = new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
//            PrintStream pstream = new PrintStream(out);
//            pstream.print(postdat);
//            pstream.close();
            } catch (java.net.MalformedURLException ex) {
                //Toast.makeText(this, ex.toString(), duration ).show();
            } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
                //Toast.makeText(this, ex.toString(), duration).show();
            }
            return null;
        }

    };
```

**2. PHP Code(update.php)**

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$m_lat=$_POST['latitude'];
$m_lng=$_POST['longitude'];
$m_code=$_POST['code'];
$query="update `location` set `longitude`='$m_lng',`latitude`='$m_lat' where `code`='$m_code'";
mysqli_query($connect,$query);
mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

**3. AndroidManifest.xml File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.project.nikhil.gpslocation">
<permission
    android:name="com.javapapers.currentlocationinmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.javapapers.currentlocationinmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="MyKey" />
    <activity
        android:name=".update"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_update"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And I also want to update longitude and latitude every 10 seconds.
This is my first app. I'm at beginning level of Android development.

Now my PHP code can be seen at: student.96.lt/Android/test.php

Comment: from where you are calling asynchronous task?and how you getting lat and lng values manually or using Location Listener?

Comment: using Location Listener and within AsyncTask I'm including this. I get this lat and lng from LocationManager

Comment: okay fine then call the Anynchrnous inside onLocationChanged() then it will call everytime when the location is changed.

Comment: Your `update.php` contains some SQL injection vulnerabilities - don't put it live like this. I expect this could do with some authentication and rate-limiting too - someone could null all of your locations as it stands.

Comment: No, my problem still not solved, I've also posted same question on stackoverflow, there also I didn't get any response.

Comment: @NikhilBansode: I did not see your reply to me, please use `@halfer` (or whatever name) when replying to people (it has tab completion).

Comment: This seems like a classic debugging problem. You need to find out (1) if your HTTP operation being sent? and (2) is the HTTP operation being received? Use file operations or whatever other debugging systems to check this.